# Resize window and keep page elements where there at, waiting until resize is over

Tags: jquery, window, width, jquery-animate

Using jQuery's window resize function, is there a way to create these  two functions.

1. It will keep the page-wraps width where it's at, during the resize. Thus, we would lock everything in place until the resize & it's resize timer event is over.
2. Once it is over, the width will .animate smoothly to new window width...

inspiration is http://bit.ly/kDurZ4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

```
    $(window).resize( function() {

        function smoothResize() {

            // animate the width on resize
            $('#container').animate({

                'width' : $(window).width()-15

            });

        }

        // This calls the function 'smoothResize' when the browser has finished resizing
        clearTimeout(this.id);
        this.id = setTimeout(smoothResize, 50);

    });
```

You will need some if's to detect screen size and whether the div is within the constraints and needs to be resized.

Comment: This works great and is therefore solved. As an addon, I need to find where to place a callback function for .animate function that will turn off BODY{} overflow so that there is no scrollbar visible during the smooth transition. I will also get the easing plugin to work on my own.